# Aiohttp StreamReader differencies in methods iter_chunked, iter_any, iter_chunks

Tags: python, streamreader, aiohttp

In documentation https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html there are three methods for async dealing with response in chunks:

- `iter_chunked: Iterates over data chunks with maximum size limit`
- `iter_any: Iterates over data chunks in order of intaking them into the stream`
- `iter_chunks: Iterates over data chunks as received from the server`

I don't understand what's the differencies between them and what should I use for downloading file in chunks.

`as received from the server` - what does that mean? Is only difference with iter_chunked is that iter_chunked comes with maximum size param?

`intaking them into the stream` - how it differs from `as received from the server`?

Answer (score 0):

`iter_chunked` is used if you know the maximum size of the content, but not all servers give a Content-Length header, despite the fact that there is a file in the response (This is because some servers violate the standards and implement their own logic), so `iter_chunks` should be an any case solution wether you know the max size or not. No clue about `iter_any`. If I were you I would test `iter_chunks` first before `iter_any`, there are examples of both at the docs AFAIK

Alternatively, you can to download a file with the aiohttp client using a while loop like this:

```
mb=1024*1024
filename="file.bin"
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        async with aiofiles.open(filename,"wb") as f:
            while True:
                chunk=await response.content.read(mb)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                await f.write(chunk)
```

aiofiles.open() is an async version of open()
More info on aiofiles here: https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/